# ListView onItemClickListener not working within fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I know there is a few dozens of these posts, however even after hours of searching and trying different solutions I have not been able to make my list view work.

The ListView is within a fragment, which also contaains a TextView, and is the reason it is not a ListFragment. This fragment is within an Activity that contains the Fragment as a Framelayout and a Button.

The ListView is getting populated with data, but clicking on one of these items nothing happens.

**Activity**

```
public class TurnOnHeadbandActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MuseManagerAndroid manager = null;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.turn_on_headband_activity);

        // XX this must come before other libmuse API calls; it loads the
        // library.
        manager = MuseManagerAndroid.getInstance();
        manager.setContext(this);
        manager.startListening();

        handler.post(tickUi);
    }

    private final Runnable tickUi = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Muse> pairedMuses = manager.getMuses();
            if (pairedMuses.size() >= 1) {
                Fragment connectedFragment = new TurnOnHeadbandConnectedFragment();
                PairedMuses pairedMusesObject = new PairedMuses(pairedMuses);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("pairedMuses", pairedMusesObject);
                connectedFragment.setArguments(args);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.turnOnFragment, connectedFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
            handler.postDelayed(tickUi, 1000 / 60);
        }
    };
}
```

**XML for Activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nightsky">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/turnOnFragment"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/faqbutton"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:text="FAQ"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
public class TurnOnHeadbandConnectedFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView museListView;

    public TurnOnHeadbandConnectedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.turn_on_headband_connected_fragment, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        PairedMuses pairedMuses = (PairedMuses)bundle.getSerializable("pairedMuses");

         // Fetch the names and MacAddresses of connected muses and store them in string array
         int musesAmount = pairedMuses.getPairedMuses().size();
         String[] musesMacAddresses = new String[musesAmount];
         for (int i = 0; i < musesAmount; i++) {
             musesMacAddresses[i] = String.valueOf(pairedMuses.getPairedMuses().get(i).getName().concat(pairedMuses.getPairedMuses().get(i).getMacAddress()));
         }

         museListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.museListView);
         ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, musesMacAddresses);
         museListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
         museListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

         return rootView;
     }

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
         intent.putExtra("id", id);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

**XML for Fragment**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context="com.musesleep.musesleep.TurnOnHeadbandConnectedFragment"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:text="Select your headband from the list:"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/museListView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML for custom ListView Item**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#40D3D3D3"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `focusable` attribute in the XML or setting it as true? Also you should replace the height with 0dp and put a `layout_weight=1`. This will ensure that the view fits in the screen

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `tickUi` `Runnable`? Specifically, why are you trying to run it 60 times a second? I'm not surprised none of your click events are registering, what with that `Fragment` being repeatedly replaced that rapidly.

Comment: I have not tried to set it to true, however I have tried without having it, as it have been added due to trying fixing the issue.

Comment: If that doesn't work try adding `clickable=false` to the TextView.

Comment: @MikeM. The tickUI Runnable is there to replace the fragment when a connection to a Muse headband have been found. The 60 times a second is overkill, will agree, and simply only there due to copy-paste from another project. I have an onPause with removeCallbacks on the handler, will this stop the replacement, or am I missing something?

Comment: @MikeM. I tried upping the delay time, and as you mentioned this is where the mistake was.

Comment: Well, that would, but when the `Activity` is paused, which doesn't happen just from loading a `Fragment`. As soon as `manager.getMuses()` returns a non-empty list, you're trying to replace that `Fragment` 60 times a second. I think what you meant to do is have the `handler.postDelayed()` in an `else` on that `if`. However, that's still not a great way to do that, the constant polling. I've never even heard of Muse, but I would imagine it's got a listener interface that's meant for this sort of thing.

Comment: Like [the `MuseListener` interface](http://android.choosemuse.com/classcom_1_1choosemuse_1_1libmuse_1_1_muse_listener.html), if I'm looking at the right thing, set with the [`MuseManagerAndroid#setMuseListener()` method](http://android.choosemuse.com/classcom_1_1choosemuse_1_1libmuse_1_1_muse_manager_android.html#a4a75cc6aa4d1116cd242219713082d19)

Comment: @MikeM. You are most likely to be correct and I should have looked for a listener like that, but chose the lazy way and copy-pasted a code piece meant for a different job. Will look into the museListener as you been so kindly to spend time finding that one.